# Event for the button inside does not work by stopPropagation

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

I have a small problem, namely:

I wrote a script that when it clicks on an overlay dialog box closes it. In addition, the dialog box contains a button to close dynamically loaded via the .html () function.

The problem is that if I use e.stopPropagation () for the container dialog box (classmodal), the .close-modal button stops working.

How can I fix this?

```js
$(".modal").html('<a class="close-modal" href="#">close</a> <a href="#">do any stuff</a>');

$(".modal-overlay").on("click", function(e) {

  $(this).fadeOut("slow");

});

$(document).on("click", ".close-modal", function(e) {

  $(".modal-overlay").fadeOut("slow");

});

$(".modal").on("click", function(e) {

  e.stopPropagation();

});
```

```css
.modal-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-overlay">
  <div class="modal">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Event stop propagation will stop the subsequent events, there by in your case .modal click event will fire first and stop propagation will stop the invocation of .close-modal and .modal-overlay events. 

    To handle this, you can use the below code.

        $(".modal").on("click", function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is($(this)))
          e.stopPropagation();
        });

    Hope it helps! Happy coding!!!
```

Comment: oops, doesn't work. if i click into the modal content - modal disappears

Comment: As per your above code, you have written to fade out modal overlay on click of close modal. That is what happening now. Can you please elaborate your problem statement?